# How to plot date and time in X axis against Y value (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Data**

```
2018.05.01,01:15,1.206870,1.206920,1.206870,1.206920,0
2018.05.01,01:16,1.206910,1.206910,1.206810,1.206820,0
```

**Code**

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates    

data1 = pd.read_csv('DAT_MT_EURUSD_M1_201805.csv')

date, time, closep, highp, openp = np.loadtxt(data1, 
                                              delimiter=',',
                                              unpack = True,
                                              dtype=float,
                                              converters ={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d%H:%M')})
```

At the end have an error

> ValueError: time data u'2018.05.01' does not match format
>   '%Y%m%d%H:%M'

It seems like i have to write a converter function to fit the proper date format, but I don't know how.

Please suggest.

Comment: It seems that your dates have periods and other punctuation that your format string lacks. Also you're splitting with commas so that some times are being interpreted as dates.

Comment: What is `bytespdate2num` ?

Comment: Some `import` statements are missing, like `from matplotlib.dates import bytespdate2num` and `import pandas as pd` in order to make your code almost ready-to-use.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the format to `%Y.%m.%d` should do the trick, you're missing the dots in between.

If not you can also try `dateutil` which parses most of the date formats for you:

```
import dateutil

dateutil.parser.parse(my_date_str)
```

Comment: That won't quite fix his code since he also has times like `01:16` being interpreted by that same format string (he's splitting the file by commas, which is splitting his datetime segments in half).

Comment: @HansMusgrave Yeah, thanks for pointing out! I just noticed the date format is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

Your date and time are separated by a comma, which you are splitting on, so you are getting incorrect results.  You should pre-format your file to remove that first comma:

```
data = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    data.append(line.replace(',', ' ', 1))

with open('test.txt', 'w') as outf:
  outf.write(''.join(data))

# 2018.05.01 01:15,1.206870,1.206920,1.206870,1.206920,0
# 2018.05.01 01:16,1.206910,1.206910,1.206810,1.206820,0
```

#### Make sure you only run this once or else more commas will be removed.

Which can then easily be parsed into a time using pandas (which you're already using):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None)
pd.to_datetime(df[0])

0   2018-05-01 01:15:00
1   2018-05-01 01:16:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly ask `pd.read_csv()` to parse the date and time with the `parse_date` keyword argument:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data AND parse time stamps (date + time) given by columns 0 and 1
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=None, parse_dates=[0, 1])

# Plot and save figure
plt.plot(data[[1]], data[[2, 3, 4, 5]])
plt.savefig('pandas_plot.png')
```

Given the two lines of data you provided (that I stored in the `data.csv` file), this script produces the following figure (where you can actually see your data sampled at two different dates):

[image: plotting data with pandas and matplotlit]